# 'void' type not allowed here - is there a workaround?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, void

I use the library [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

Object is created in a simple loop (`cinema.start(i, j)` returns a valid JSON-Object):

```
JSONObject cinemaJSON = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (cinema.start(i, j) != null)
                    cinemaJSON = cinema.start(i, j);
            }
        }
```

Then I try to merge two JSON-Objects and print it (`cinema2.start("value")` returns a valid object, too):

```
System.out.println(cinemaJSON.putAll(cinema2.start("value")));
```

And at this point I get the error: **'void' type not allowed here**

Are there ways to alternative implementation of my code to make it possible to display the result of the merger of two objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`putAll()` is a `void` method(nothing return). So you can try this way

```
cinemaJSON.putAll(cinema2.start("value"))
```

Now print

```
System.out.println(cinemaJSON);
```

Answer (score 2):

JSONObject [putAll](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) returns `void` and hence sysout statement complains for it.

Just split the statement

```
System.out.println(cinemaJSON.putAll(cinema2.start("value")));
```

into two:

```
cinemaJSON.putAll(cinema2.start("value"));
System.out.println(cinemaJSON);
```